# Java OOP; creating several objects

Tags: java, object, constructor

I am trying to store students' data in main class, in the student class I did the following:

```
public class Student {
        public static String name = "UNKNOWN";
        Student(){

        }

        Student(String name) {
            this.name = name;}
```

While in main I did the following:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        //s1 is short for student1
        Student s1 = new Student ("Chris");
        Student s2 = new Student ("Layla");
        Student s3 = new Student ("Mark");
```

This issue is, whenever I print a sx.name I'd always print the last one. So for the following code:

```
System.out.println(s1.name);
```

I'd get *Mark*, while it should be *Chris*.

Comment: Just remove static keyword in name field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Because static fields are shared by all the objects.
Please change your code as follows:

```
public class Student {
        public String name;
        Student(){

        }

        Student(String name) {
            this.name = name;
```

}

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        //s1 is short for student1
        Student s1 = new Student ("Chris");
        Student s2 = new Student ("Layla");
        Student s3 = new Student ("Mark");
}
```

[When to use static in java?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

> Sometimes, you want to have variables that are common to all objects.
> This is accomplished with the static modifier. Fields that have the
> static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class
> variables. They are associated with the class, rather than with any
> object. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is
> in one fixed location in memory. Any object can change the value of a
> class variable, but class variables can also be manipulated without
> creating an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The static variable `name` is accessed by instances, which is not recommended in Java. You can make it non-static. The IDE, such as IDEA, will give you some hint/warning about this issue, like:
[image]

So with the help of IDEs, you can easily find some potential issues.